# [PHP][HTML] Create a list of songs, press play button to play the selected song

Tags: audio, php, web-interface

I am trying to achieve the following :
I want to start a selected song on the rpi from a web interface.

I can play the song through exec

```
exec("mpg123 /var/www/html/Sounds/Zelda.mp3",$status);
```

and I can create a list dynamically through /var/www/html/Sounds

```
<?php
$arr_files = scandir("/var/www/html/Sounds/");
echo "<select name =\"songlist\" size=\"5\">";

foreach ($arr_files as $value){
echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}   
echo "</select>"
?>
```

How would I go about in order to take the selected song from the html select 'songlist' and then play it using the exec command by clicking a button?

So far, the only thing I am finding is how to play a song on the client, not on the server side.

Hopefully this is clear enough. Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks.

edit : I would like to say that I am a total newbie with PHP/HTML, so explanations would be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one PHP page. I personally would not I would have the processing done in a separate PHP file, but this will get you started

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['songlist'])){
    $selected = $_POST['songlist'];
    //exec("mpg123 /var/www/html/Sounds/".$selected);
    echo $selected;
}

echo "<form method='post' name='songlist'>";
$arr_files = scandir("/var/www/html/Sounds/");
echo "<select name =\"songlist\" size=\"5\">";

foreach ($arr_files as $value){ 
    echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}   
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does get me unstuck. My question is this then : can I use action = "script.php" in the input form to then call a script with the if isset section and then play the song? Is that what you meant when you said to do it in a separate file?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean :D  that way when you start styling your form it gets less confusing.